# Rename and copy bulk files

Tags: bash

I have encrypted /home/user folder. I want to copy plenty of files from my USB stick, but almost half of files have too long file names.

I want all file names to be cropped from like

> "1. asd ajsdfhka sadkjgkjsagdk sadkjhgsgdlas gasdjghkasg
>   sadgjhaskgh.odt"

to

> "1. asd ajsdfhka sadkjgkjsagdk sadkjhgsgd~.odt"

and copied to my home folder.

I'm not familiar with bash scripting. Could any one help me?

Comment: Specify which encryption tool/system have you used. Maybe it just exists a native command that deals with your problem.

Comment: Moreover __I do not suggest you to simply truncate__ the filename...  Let's suppose that you reserve 3 chars (2 numbers and the `.`) for the progressive number, but after you copy 100 mp3 files with a very long name of the album followed by the title [(see the Chumbawamba one here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Bands_Have_Won)... It's better if you extract a part of the begin and a part from the end, do the count of the ones already present in the destination directory and then you add the number+1, else you decrease of one the _filename_ length and you repeat... until you can.

Comment: It's ok, all files have a unique name.

Comment: @Hastur eCryptfs as it is native for mint 17

Comment: Give a [look here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32834/66388): _If filenames are not encrypted, then you can safely write filenames of up to 255 characters and encrypt their contents_.  If you want to encrypt filenames too you can extract substrings from a string [_Extract substring in bash_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/428580/3569208). Max [length 143 chars](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878), but I suggest you less.